# formatear un dato int a moneda local

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

tengo un base de datos y ejemplo en la vista lo llamo

```
<td>{{ $payment -> pago }}</td>
```

pero ejemplo se guarda como INT, ejemplo si tengo guardado me lo muestra asi

```
3000
```

pero yo quiero que lo muestre de esta forma

```
3,000.00
```

laravel posee algo simple para hacer eso? que lo podria hacer pasarlo a un js y de hay convertirlo... pero si ya posee eso. no quisiera generar codigo de mas. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este caso la respuesta no la tiene Laravel sino PHP, con la función number_format() :

```
{{ number_format($payment->pago, 2) }}
```

Aquí la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php

Comment: gracias una vez mas, si